# converting a react app from classes to hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this Pomodoro react app written in classes, and I would like to convert to hooks.

```
import React from 'react';
import SetTimer from './components/SetTimer';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    breakCount: 5,
    sessionCount: 25,
    clockCount: 25 * 60,
    currentTimer: 'Session',
    isPlaying: false,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loop = undefined;
    this.handlePlayPause = this.handlePlayPause.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.loop);
  }

  handlePlayPause() {
    const { isPlaying } = this.state;
    console.log(isPlaying);
    if (isPlaying) {
      //if the time is playing and we press this button, then we need to puase or clear the playing intervals
      clearInterval(this.loop);
      this.setState({ isPlaying: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isPlaying: true });
      this.loop = setInterval(() => {
        const {
          clockCount,
          breakCount,
          sessionCount,
          currentTimer,
        } = this.state;
        if (clockCount === 0) {
          this.setState({
            currentTimer: currentTimer === 'Session' ? 'Break' : 'Session',
            clockCount:
              currentTimer === 'Session' ? breakCount * 60 : sessionCount * 60,
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ clockCount: clockCount - 1 });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      breakCount: 5,
      sessionCount: 25,
      clockCount: 25 * 60,
      currentTimer: 'Session',
      isPlaying: false,
    });
    clearInterval(this.loop);
  };

  convertTime = (count) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    let seconds = count % 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  };

  handleBreakDecrease = () => {
    const { breakCount } = this.state;
    if (breakCount >= 2) {
      this.setState({ breakCount: breakCount - 1 });
    }
  };
  handleBreakIncrease = () => {
    const { breakCount } = this.state;
    this.setState({ breakCount: breakCount + 1 });
  };
  handleSessionDecrease = () => {
    const { sessionCount } = this.state;
    if (sessionCount >= 2) {
      this.setState({
        sessionCount: sessionCount - 1,
        clockCount: (sessionCount - 1) * 60,
      });
    }
  };
  handleSessionIncrease = () => {
    const { sessionCount } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      sessionCount: sessionCount + 1,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { breakCount, sessionCount, clockCount, currentTimer } = this.state;
    const breakProps = {
      title: 'Break Length',
      count: breakCount,
      handleDecrease: this.handleBreakDecrease,
      handleIncrease: this.handleBreakIncrease,
    };

    const sessionProps = {
      title: 'Session Length',
      count: sessionCount,
      handleDecrease: this.handleSessionDecrease,
      handleIncrease: this.handleSessionIncrease,
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className='flex'>
          <SetTimer {...breakProps} />
          <SetTimer {...sessionProps} />
        </div>
        <div className='clock-container'>
          <h1>{currentTimer}</h1>
          <span>{this.convertTime(clockCount)}</span>
          <div className='flex'>
            <button onClick={this.handlePlayPause}>
              {this.state.isPlaying ? (
                <i className={`fas fa-pause`}></i>
              ) : (
                <i className='fas fa-play'></i>
              )}
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.handleReset}>
              <i className='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I did the following changes, and although everything seems to be working, one critical thing that isn't is the `setInterval` function inside the `handlePlayPause` function that runs only once. I wonder why!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SetTimer from './components/SetTimer';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  let loop = undefined;

  const [timeVariables, setTimeVariables] = useState({
    breakCount: 5,
    sessionCount: 25,
    clockCount: 25 * 60,
    currentTimer: 'Session',
    isPlaying: false,
  });

  const {
    breakCount,
    sessionCount,
    clockCount,
    currentTimer,
    isPlaying,
  } = timeVariables;

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(loop);
    };
  }, []);

  const handlePlayPause = () => {
    const { isPlaying } = timeVariables;
    if (isPlaying) {
      clearInterval(loop);
      setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, isPlaying: false });
    } else {
      setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, isPlaying: true });
      loop = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('Hello');
        const {
          clockCount,
          breakCount,
          sessionCount,
          currentTimer,
        } = timeVariables;
        if (clockCount === 0) {
          setTimeVariables({
            ...timeVariables,
            currentTimer: currentTimer === 'Session' ? 'Break' : 'Session',
            clockCount:
              currentTimer === 'Session' ? breakCount * 60 : sessionCount * 60,
          });
        } else {
          setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, clockCount: clockCount - 1 });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
  const handleReset = () => {
    setTimeVariables({
      breakCount: 5,
      sessionCount: 25,
      clockCount: 25 * 60,
      currentTimer: 'Session',
      isPlaying: false,
    });
    clearInterval(loop);
  };

  const convertTime = (count) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    let seconds = count % 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  };

  const handleBreakDecrease = () => {
    const { breakCount } = timeVariables;
    if (breakCount >= 2) {
      setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, breakCount: breakCount - 1 });
    }
  };
  const handleBreakIncrease = () => {
    const { breakCount } = timeVariables;
    setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, breakCount: breakCount + 1 });
  };
  const handleSessionDecrease = () => {
    const { sessionCount } = timeVariables;
    if (sessionCount >= 2) {
      setTimeVariables({
        ...timeVariables,
        sessionCount: sessionCount - 1,
        clockCount: (sessionCount - 1) * 60,
      });
    }
  };
  const handleSessionIncrease = () => {
    const { sessionCount } = timeVariables;
    setTimeVariables({
      ...timeVariables,
      sessionCount: sessionCount + 1,
      clockCount: (sessionCount + 1) * 60,
    });
  };

  const breakProps = {
    title: 'Break Length',
    count: breakCount,
    handleDecrease: handleBreakDecrease,
    handleIncrease: handleBreakIncrease,
  };

  const sessionProps = {
    title: 'Session Length',
    count: sessionCount,
    handleDecrease: handleSessionDecrease,
    handleIncrease: handleSessionIncrease,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='flex'>
        <SetTimer {...breakProps} />
        <SetTimer {...sessionProps} />
      </div>
      <div className='clock-container'>
        <h1>{currentTimer}</h1>
        <span>{convertTime(clockCount)}</span>
        <div className='flex'>
          <button onClick={handlePlayPause}>
            {isPlaying ? (
              <i className={`fas fa-pause`}></i>
            ) : (
              <i className='fas fa-play'></i>
            )}
          </button>
          <button onClick={handleReset}>
            <i className='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Update**: with individual state variables

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SetTimer from './components/SetTimer';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  console.log('rendered');
  let loop = undefined;
  // const [loop, setLoop] = useState(undefined);
  const [breakCount, setBreakCount] = useState(5);
  const [sessionCount, setSessionCount] = useState(25);
  const [clockCount, setClockCount] = useState(25 * 60);
  const [currentTimer, setCurrentTimer] = useState('Session');
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  // const [timeVariables, setTimeVariables] = useState({
  //   breakCount: 5,
  //   sessionCount: 25,
  //   clockCount: 25 * 60,
  //   currentTimer: 'Session',
  //   isPlaying: false,
  // });

  // const {
  //   breakCount,
  //   sessionCount,
  //   clockCount,
  //   currentTimer,
  //   isPlaying,
  // } = timeVariables;

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   // setClockCount(
  //   //   currentTimer === 'Session' ? sessionCount * 60 : breakCount * 60
  //   // );
  //   return () => {
  //     clearInterval(loop);
  //   };
  // }, []);

  const handlePlayPause = () => {
    // const { isPlaying } = timeVariables;
    if (isPlaying) {
      console.log(loop, isPlaying);
      clearInterval(loop);
      setIsPlaying(false);
    } else {
      loop = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(loop, isPlaying);
        setIsPlaying(true);
        // const {
        //   clockCount,
        //   breakCount,
        //   sessionCount,
        //   currentTimer,
        // } = timeVariables;
        if (clockCount === 0) {
          setCurrentTimer(currentTimer === 'Session' ? 'Break' : 'Session');
          setClockCount(
            currentTimer === 'Session' ? breakCount * 60 : sessionCount * 60
          );
          // setTimeVariables({
          //   ...timeVariables,
          //   currentTimer: currentTimer === 'Session' ? 'Break' : 'Session',
          //   clockCount:
          //     currentTimer === 'Session' ? breakCount * 60 : sessionCount * 60,
          // });
        } else {
          setClockCount((clockCount) => clockCount - 1);
          // setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, clockCount: clockCount - 1 });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
  const handleReset = () => {
    setBreakCount(5);
    setSessionCount(25);
    setClockCount(25 * 60);
    setCurrentTimer('Session');
    setIsPlaying(false);
    // setTimeVariables({
    //   breakCount: 5,
    //   sessionCount: 25,
    //   clockCount: 25 * 60,
    //   currentTimer: 'Session',
    //   isPlaying: false,
    // });
    clearInterval(loop);
  };

  const convertTime = (count) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    let seconds = count % 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  };

  const handleBreakDecrease = () => {
    // const { breakCount } = timeVariables;
    if (breakCount >= 2) {
      setBreakCount(breakCount - 1);
      // setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, breakCount: breakCount - 1 });
    }
  };
  const handleBreakIncrease = () => {
    // const { breakCount } = timeVariables;
    setBreakCount(breakCount + 1);
    // setTimeVariables({ ...timeVariables, breakCount: breakCount + 1 });
  };
  const handleSessionDecrease = () => {
    // const { sessionCount } = timeVariables;
    if (sessionCount >= 2) {
      setSessionCount(sessionCount - 1);
      setClockCount((sessionCount - 1) * 60);
      // setTimeVariables({
      //   ...timeVariables,
      //   sessionCount: sessionCount - 1,
      //   clockCount: (sessionCount - 1) * 60,
      // });
    }
  };
  const handleSessionIncrease = () => {
    setSessionCount(sessionCount + 1);
    setClockCount((sessionCount + 1) * 60);
    // const { sessionCount } = timeVariables;
    // setTimeVariables({
    //   ...timeVariables,
    //   sessionCount: sessionCount + 1,
    //   clockCount: (sessionCount + 1) * 60,
    // });
  };

  const breakProps = {
    title: 'Break Length',
    count: breakCount,
    handleDecrease: handleBreakDecrease,
    handleIncrease: handleBreakIncrease,
  };

  const sessionProps = {
    title: 'Session Length',
    count: sessionCount,
    handleDecrease: handleSessionDecrease,
    handleIncrease: handleSessionIncrease,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='flex'>
        <SetTimer {...breakProps} />
        <SetTimer {...sessionProps} />
      </div>
      <div className='clock-container'>
        <h1>{currentTimer}</h1>
        <span>{convertTime(clockCount)}</span>
        <div className='flex'>
          <button onClick={handlePlayPause}>
            {isPlaying ? (
              <i className={`fas fa-pause`}></i>
            ) : (
              <i className='fas fa-play'></i>
            )}
          </button>
          <button onClick={handleReset}>
            <i className='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

A quite clear difference between the 2 versions is that
In the former, loop is in the state.
But in the latter, loop is just a variable.

You may want to useState for loop as well. However, I am strongly against using useState with objects (and arrays). It is shallowly compared, so it may not be correct at times.

I know it's frustrating when you have to useState for each single field. Take a look at useReducer. Check this post. It may help. https://dev.to/max_frolov_/react-hooks-usereducer-complex-state-handling-243k

Comment: My plan is to implement this with redux eventually, but for now I need it to be working. I tried to separate the states into their own `useState` hooks, but nothing has changed. And when I added `loop` as a component state variable, and then assigned it a `setInterval`, I got an error saying that `loop` is constant, which I think is logical since it can only be updated now using the second returned value from the `useState` hook.

Comment: Have you tried this?
```
const [loop, setLoop] = useState(null);
```

Comment: I guess something like `loop = setInterval()` or `setLoop(setInterval)` is not correct. 
The former, you can't assign directly like that, at least it should look like the latter. And the latter, setInterval will be called in each render and `loop` may have new value. 

And if you shouldn't have 2 consecutive setState like 2 setTimeVariables, one changing the isPlaying, one changing clockCount. It should be in just one setState as right after the first setState is called, it will re-render the component and may produce unexpected behaviors

Comment: I suspect I need to put some code in the `useEffect` hook, but not sure what and how.

Comment: I updated my post with individual state variables. When I used `setClockCount((clockCount) => clockCount - 1)` instead of `setClockCount(clockCount - 1)` the clock started to count down fine, but the pause button doesn't work, i.e., the clock keeps counting down. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, but you can have a try. I guess the problem may come from loop is not a state variable and the way you set loop 
https://pastebin.com/yJaxhn9V

Comment: OK, that made the clock to stops when I press pause. Thanks. Now I am facing another problem which is that the `clockCount` in `handlePlayPause` doesn't actually change, and the clock keeps decrementing even after it reach 0!!

Comment: `if (clockCount === 0) {` I think this part can be moved outside of the function and here `useEffect` can be helpful. useEffect is a callback which is triggered when some value is changed. 
I think you can make it watching for changes of clockCount like

`useEffect(() => { if (clockCount === 0 ) {} }, [clockCount])`

Comment: That's correct. I did implement the logic inside `useEffect` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954283/problem-with-timer-in-javascript-especially-when-tab-is-inactive?noredirect=1#comment113092261_63954283), but now the timer drifts with time in React, but it doesn't in vanilla JS, I wonder why!