# Problem with timer in JavaScript especially when tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this timer in ReactJS that uses the computer's clock's time to run, which is supposedly more accurate than incrementing/decrementing the timer by 1 using `setInterval` with interval of 1 second. However, even when relying on the computer's clock, the timer's time drifts (by comparing it to this [clock](https://www.online-stopwatch.com/countdown-timer/) my app timer drifted 3 seconds in delay after 15 minutes running), and at some point it even stopped completely, while using other tabs **in purpose**.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [sessionTime, setSessionTime] = useState(82.5);
  const [breakTime, setBreakTime] = useState(7.5);
  const [clockTime, setClockTime] = useState(82.5 * 60);
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('session');
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = convertTime(clockTime);
    if (isPlaying) {
      let startTime = new Date();
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (clockTime === 0) {
          setCurrent(current === 'session' ? 'break' : 'session');
          setClockTime(
            current === 'session' ? breakTime * 60 : sessionTime * 60
          );
        } else {
          setClockTime(
            clockTime - (new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000
          );
          // }
        }
      }, 200);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    }
  }, [isPlaying, clockTime]);

  const handlePlayClick = () => {
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  const handlePauseClick = () => [setIsPlaying(false)];

  const convertTime = (count) => {
    let hours = Math.floor(count / 3600);
    let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) - hours * 60;
    let seconds = parseFloat(count % 60).toFixed(0);
    if (hours < 10) hours = `0${hours}`;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = `0${minutes}`;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = `0${seconds}`;
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <span>{convertTime(clockTime)}</span>
      <span>{current}</span>
      {isPlaying ? (
        <button onClick={handlePauseClick}>Pause</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handlePlayClick}>Play</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My questions is **How can I create accurate timers in ReactJS/JavaScript that don't drift, and keep running accurately even when the tab in which they are running is inactive? How timers like this [clock](https://www.online-stopwatch.com/countdown-timer/) is created, and why it's accurate? Do I get better results if I get the timer from a backend?**

Comment: I think the problem is react itself. Each time you update the state it renders the UI again. Take a look at the react docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element) and maybe you wrap the whole component with a setInterval. it is also interesting to know, that there is a page lifecycle (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api)

Comment: Hmmm, after reading your post I implemented the counter in Vanilla JavaScript, and ran it along with the online clock I mentioned (my app timer was 1 second ahead because I needed to switch tabs to start the online clock after I started my app clock), and interestingly, the 1 second difference was maintained for about 13 minutes, until the online clock stopped (I opened 25 YouTube videos and played them to simulate heavy duty work on other tabs). The question now is: **why exactly the React code doesn't work as well?** Did I implement it wrongly?